# Getting bad index key pattern error using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am getting one error related to mongodb.Actually i have one collection whose datas are given below.

```
"_id" : ObjectId("55bd9b7adfa5d64c057de74f"),
 "username" : "admin",
 "emailid" : "*****************************",
 "password" : "adminuser",
 "image" : "images/Image0895.jpg",
 "firstname" : "subhrajyoti",
 "lastname" : "pradhan"
```

Here i want to keep the username document as unique.For that i wrote the command`db.collectionname.createIndex( {"username":"admin"},{unique:true})`.But it gave me the following error.

> Error:

```
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "bad index key pattern { username: \"admin\" }: Unknown index
 plugin 'admin'",
        "code" : 67
```

Please help me to resolve this error keep my one document as unique for this collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a unique index on username field you'd use this command:

```
db.collectionname.createIndex( {"username": 1},{unique:true})
```

The value of the username key must be 1 (indexed ascending) or -1 (indexed descending)

See MongoDB docs on [db.collection.createIndex()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/)